# How do you find the largest and smallest numbers in a java text file?

Tags: java

My professor asked me to write a program that would analyze a text file and print out the minimum and maximum values of that file. I wrote the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class findMaxAndMin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File myFile = new File("NumberFile.txt");
        try {
            Scanner doubleScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
            while (doubleScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                double currentDouble = doubleScanner.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(currentDouble);
                double biggestNumber = doubleScanner.nextDouble();
                double smallestNumber = doubleScanner.nextDouble();
                if (currentDouble > biggestNumber) {
                    currentDouble = biggestNumber;
                }
                if (currentDouble < smallestNumber) {
                    currentDouble = smallestNumber;
                }
                System.out.println("The largest number is " + biggestNumber);
                System.out.println("the smallest number is " + smallestNumber);
            }
        } catch (Exception l) {
            System.err.println(l.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I ended up with this obviously inaccurate, messed-up output in my Git command line:

```
$ java findMaxAndMin
100.0

The largest number is 200.0

the smallest number is 20.0

2.0

The largest number is 550.0

the smallest number is 7000.0
```

The text file had the values:

100

200

20

2

550

7000

So, the program should have printed out two statements, declaring that "the smallest number is 2," and "the largest number is 7000." How can I easily correct this code? I'm not an experienced programmer. Prompt replies would be greatly appreciated, because this assignment is due at midnight.

Comment: Every time you call `nextDouble()` you will get the **next** value in the file, so you should only call `nextDouble()` once inside the loop. --- Please fix the indentations of your code. I almost missed the loop because of your bad formatting.

Comment: If my post has answered your question, I'd appreciate if you accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be going about like this if I were you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File myFile = new File("NumberFile.txt");
        try {
            Scanner doubleScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
            double bigDouble = Double.MIN_VALUE; //Initialize with a very small value
            double smallDouble = Double.MAX_VALUE; //Initialize with a very big value
            double currentDouble;
            while (doubleScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                currentDouble = doubleScanner.nextDouble();
                if (currentDouble > bigDouble) {
                    bigDouble = currentDouble; //find the biggest number in file
                }
                if (currentDouble < smallDouble) {
                    smallDouble = currentDouble; //find the smallest number in the file
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The largest number is " + bigDouble); //print the number outside the while loop
            System.out.println("the smallest number is " + smallDouble);
        } catch (Exception l) {
            System.err.println(l.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the output you shall see:

[image: Output from the input file]

Since you are new to programming, I have added comments to help a bit. I'd suggest you fiddle and play around with the code a bit to understand how changes impact the output.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading the code out loud. This is a basic method of debugging, known as [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

College is about learning.  If I found the issue, and showed it to you, I would actually be hurting your learning.  (A good grade is great, but earning it is even better!)

Comment: Another method of debugging is to use `System.out.println(...)` after almost every line, to log the value of a variable that you are not sure about.